# CSS float issue

Tags: css-float

I have a page where there are two images on top which are floated to left and right as below :

```
.floatLeft{ float:left;}
.floatRight{ float:right; }


    <div>
        <img src="firstImage"  class="floatLeft"/>
        <img src="secondImage" class="floatRight"/>

        <!-- wright here -->


    </div>
```

Issue is when i write anything after images (be it in div or a plain text ) and if it goes beyong page width , 
the text after maximum width shifts downwords entirely after images . That is text doesn't wrap inbetween two images 
What i understand about float is text should "FLOW" in between two images (unless we use clear which "clears" area around images ) , but its not working like that. 
I want to have a text in between two images.

Any help is higly appreciated as a I have done a lot of efforts but it is not working.

Comment: can you tell the structure you want the text between two images or two images then the text will it be over the image or below it

Comment: He wrote that text should float between images, but if text is longer than a space between images it does not wrap and goes after images next line. All info is provided. So it doesn't matter. If he wraps the content in DIVs (or TDs), it will be possible then to manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the answer that you need [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sr8p/4/)

I will explain a little about.
in your div add a class of imgcontainer
in your css, add the following

```
.imgcontainer{
    position:relative;
}
```

you can add the width of the div, in jsfiddle I set it as 150px. and each of the image is 50px. there you add paragraph with some text

Comment: Your JSFiddle shows text is going next line and after it there is an image. It doesn't answer the question. The question was how to AVOID it. Right?

Comment: The question is to avoid it goes to the next line but rather the text continue from the first image and it does. The width of the div and some css need to be edited to suit the purposes. http://jsfiddle.net/6Sr8p/3/ here I updated if you want it to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, you have 3 blocks of data here, so I suggest using 3 floating divs with set width:

```
.floatLeft{ float:left}
.div1{width:X%}
.div2{width:Y%}
.div3{width:Z%}
.overflow{overflow: hidden} /* this is optional */

<div class="overflow">
    <div class="floatLeft div1">
        <img src="firstImage"/>
    </div">
    <div class="floatLeft div2">
        <!-- text here -->
    </div">
    <div class="floatLeft div3"><!-- or make it float right if you want -->
        <img src="secondImage"/>
    </div">
</div>
```

If you want your images a fixed width, try using CSS calc:

```
.div1{width:100px}
.div2{width:-moz-calc(100%-300px);-webkit-calc(100%-300px);calc(100%-300px);} /* not supported in some browsers */
.div3{width:200px}
```

But honestly I recommend to go classic way and use a table here:

```
.table {width:100%;border-collapse:collapse}
.table td {padding:0;margin:0}
.block1 {width:X%} /* or width:Xpx */
.block3 {width:Z%} /* or width:Zpx */
/* do not touch block2 here */

<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td class='block1'>
            <img src="firstImage"/>
        </td>
        <td class='block2'>
            <!-- text here -->
        </td>
        <td class='block3'>
            <img src="secondImage"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Remember to wrap your content in "blocks", it always helps when you mark up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div>
<img src="firstImage"  class="floatLeft"/>
<p class="floatLeft">Some textgoes here</p>
<img src="secondImage" class="floatRight"/>
</div>
```

but give proper width

Answer (score 0):

Another variation is using a CSS version of the table approach proposed by igorpavlov. You have to replace the table/tr/td by divs and to adapt the CSS as proposed here :

```
.table {width:100%; display: table;}
div{ display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
.block1 {width:33%} /* or width:Xpx */
.block3 {width:33%} /* or width:Zpx */
img {width: 100%; height: auto;}

<div class='table'>
    <div class='block1'>
        <img src="firstImage"/>
    </div>

    <div class='block2'>
        <!-- text here -->
    </div>

    <div class='block3'>
        <img src="secondImage"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

It provides better semantics and works IE8+!